# Setting index in graph for karateclub

Tags: python, machine-learning, graph, networkx, embedding

I am trying to create embeddings with Graph2vec from karateclub. The piece of code below works fine when `Graph2Vec(attributed = False)` but it fails with a `KeyError: 1` when `Graph2Vec(attributed = True)`. I tried converting the node names, which were being used as the index, to integers but didn't solve the issue. When I was using the node names as index, it was showing indexing error.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import igraph as ig
from karateclub import Graph2Vec

# Read network
path = "OutputFiles/Features/grapml_files/graph.graphml"
network = ig.Graph.Read_GraphML(path)
network = network.to_networkx(vertex_attr_hashable = "name")

# Create a node attribute matrix
node_attr = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Nodes"])
node_attr["Nodes"] = list(network.nodes)
node_attr["Betweenness"] = node_attr["Nodes"].map(nx.betweenness_centrality(network))
node_attr["Degree"] = node_attr["Nodes"].map(nx.degree_centrality(network))
node_attr["Closeness"] = node_attr["Nodes"].map(nx.closeness_centrality (network))
node_attr = node_attr.set_index("Nodes", drop = False)
node_attr = node_attr.to_dict(orient = "index")
nx.set_node_attributes(network, node_attr)
network = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(network, 
                                             first_label = 0, 
                                             ordering = "default", 
                                             label_attribute = "name")
# Create embedding using Graph2vec
graph2vec_model = Graph2Vec(attributed = True)
graph2vec_model.fit([network])
graph2vec_model
```

Note: The code should be reproducible with any simple graph.